# Introduce User Input as def Function Parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, syntax

I'm doing some fundamental exercises while learning from a class. One of the exercises uses def function and i thought that the example they provide is rather unrealistic so i wanted to bring it all together.

```
print("Welcome to The Car Wash Company")
print("Which service would you like to purchase?")

def wash_car(service):
    if (service == 1):
        print("Please see the selected products that will be provided to your vehicle")
        print("Wash with tri-color foam")
        print("Rinse twice")
        print("Dry with large blow dryer")
        print("Please set your vehicle to neutral and step-off the gas/break pedal at all times")

    if (service == 2):
        print("Please see the selected products that will be provided to your vehicle")
        print("Wash with white foam")
        print("Rinse once")
        print("Air dry")
        print("Please set your vehicle to neutral and step-off the gas/break pedal at all times")

    else:
        print("Sorry, We do not have the service selected at this time")
        print("Try again to choose your service from the Main Menu")

    service = input("For Premium press 1...   For Standard press 2...   ")
    if service ==1:
        print("Thank you for choosing our Premium car wash service, Please stand by.")
    if service == 2:
        print("Thank you for choosing our Standard car wash service, Please stand by.")

wash_car(service=1)

print("Thank you for choosing The Car Wash Company as your service provider!")
print("Have a wonderful rest of your day! Come again soon :)")
```

The problem I'm having is that i don't know how to define the user input of 1/2 as the choosen service to execute properly with def wash_car function. Also my else statement always triggers regardless of input value.

Thank you,

A new code enthusiast.

Comment: Might you please clarify what you mean by "how to define the user input of 1/2 as the choosen service to execute properly" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the code in the function runs in order. So the input occurs after the else statement has already executed. I'd recommend breaking the user input into a separate function, like this:

```py
print("Welcome to The Car Wash Company")
print("Which service would you like to purchase?")

def wash_car(service):
    if (service == 1):
        print("Please see the selected products that will be provided to your vehicle")
        print("Wash with tri-color foam")
        print("Rinse twice")
        print("Dry with large blow dryer")
        print("Please set your vehicle to neutral and step-off the gas/break pedal at all times")

    if (service == 2):
        print("Please see the selected products that will be provided to your vehicle")
        print("Wash with white foam")
        print("Rinse once")
        print("Air dry")
        print("Please set your vehicle to neutral and step-off the gas/break pedal at all times")

    else:
        raise ValueError


def select_service():
    service = input("For Premium press 1...   For Standard press 2...   ")
    while service not in ["1","2"]:
        print("Sorry, We do not have the service selected at this time")
        print("Try again to choose your service from the Main Menu")
        service = input("For Premium press 1...   For Standard press 2...   ")
    return int(service)

service = select_service()
wash_car(service)

print("Thank you for choosing The Car Wash Company as your service provider!")
print("Have a wonderful rest of your day! Come again soon :)")
```

This also has the benefit of automatic retry on incorrect user input.

Comment: I copy/pasted your solution and it keeps giving the same solution on terminal.

Welcome to The Car Wash Company
Which service would you like to purchase?
For Premium press 1...   For Standard press 2...   1
Sorry, We do not have the service selected at this time
Try again to choose your service from the Main Menu
For Premium press 1...   For Standard press 2...   2
Sorry, We do not have the service selected at this time
Try again to choose your service from the Main Menu
For Premium press 1...   For Standard press 2...

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention that. `Input` always returns a string, which is not ever going to be equal to an integer

Comment: @MrWalrusIII The edit I just made should fix that now

Comment: see error below

Please set your vehicle to neutral and step-off the gas/break pedal at all times
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ess576o\Documents\Learning\SW-Dev\Ex_Files_Programming_Foundations_Fundamentals\Ex_Files_Programming_Foundations_Fundamentals\Exercise Files\Chap05\05_03_begin.py", line 32, in <module>
    wash_car(service)
  File "c:\Users\ess576o\Documents\Learning\SW-Dev\Ex_Files_Programming_Foundations_Fundamentals\Ex_Files_Programming_Foundations_Fundamentals\Exercise Files\Chap05\05_03_begin.py", line 20, in wash_car
    raise ValueError
ValueError

Comment: @MrWalrusIII This line `if (service == 2):` should be `elif (service == 2):`. It's why your `else` block keeps being executed. It's not a part of the first `if`.